# Filtering a combobox by value member of the other combobox

Tags: c#, linq, filter, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes and I am filling them with Linq.

The first is a combobox named "City selection": [Displaymember: CityName, Value: CityID(int)]

When the user selects a value from the first combobox, I want to filter my second combobox by CityID.

The Second combobox for is named "Department selection".

Here is the code, but it's not working. I am getting an error on the last code block.

```
   private void cb_Bolge_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cb_Bolge.DataSource = k.tbl_Bolges;
        cb_Bolge.DisplayMember = "Bolge_Ad";
        cb_Bolge.ValueMember = "Bolge_ID";
    }

    private void cb_Bolge_ValueMemberChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cb_Departman.DataSource = k.tbl_Departmans.Where(p=>p.Bolge_ID == Convert.ToInt32(cb_Bolge.ValueMember));
        cb_Departman.DisplayMember = "Departman_Ad";
        cb_Departman.ValueMember = "Departman_ID";
    }
```

Here is the error code(sorry some of them are in Turkish by default):

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233033
Message=Giriş dizesi doğru biçimde değildi.
Source=System.Data.Linq
StackTrace:
konum:      System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression invoke)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression node)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   konum: System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   konum: System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.Provider.BindingList.Create[T](DataContext context, IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   konum: System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.GetNewBindingList()
   konum: System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.ComponentModel.IListSource.GetList()
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.SetDataSource(Object dataSource)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager..ctor(Object dataSource)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.EnsureListManager(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SetDataConnection(Object newDataSource, BindingMemberInfo newDisplayMember, Boolean force)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.set_ValueMember(String value)
   konum: TYH_Envanter.Envanter_Ekle.cb_Bolge_ValueMemberChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) c:\Users\Arda\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TYH Envanter\TYH Envanter\Envanter_Ekle.cs içinde: satır 59
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.OnValueMemberChanged(EventArgs e)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.set_ValueMember(String value)
   konum: TYH_Envanter.Envanter_Ekle.cb_Bolge_MouseHover(Object sender, EventArgs e) c:\Users\Arda\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TYH Envanter\TYH Envanter\Envanter_Ekle.cs içinde: satır 46
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnMouseHover(EventArgs e)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseHover(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   konum: TYH_Envanter.Program.Main() c:\Users\Arda\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TYH Envanter\TYH Envanter\Program.cs içinde: satır 19
   konum: System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   konum: System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   konum: Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   konum: System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   konum: System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   konum: System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   konum: System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   konum: System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
   InnerException:
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: The 2nd event should be something like SelectedValueChanged or SelectedIndexChanged ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you tell us what error message you are getting? You can edit this into your post, using the "edit" flag below your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `convert` value to `int` inside `linq expression` because this will be translated to `sql query` and `sql` has no `function Convert.ToInt32`. So you need to make a variable and save value in it and than match with this variable.

**Edit**

You are getting `cb_Bolge.ValueMember` which is `name` of property which will be `string` and it never will be converted into `int`.  So you need to get `SelectedValue`.

```
private void cb_Bolge_ValueMemberChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int blogId=Convert.ToInt32(cb_Bolge.SelectedValue);
   cb_Departman.DataSource = k.tbl_Departmans.Where(p=>p.Bolge_ID == blogId);
   cb_Departman.DisplayMember = "Departman_Ad";
   cb_Departman.ValueMember = "Departman_ID";
}
```

Comment: Did you test this ? I'm using Convert.ToInt32 in linq but did not meet any error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to call ".ToList()" on your IEnumerable, because the combo box requires a list of items (whose length is known ahead of time, which is not the case for IEnumerable).

```
cb_Departman.DataSource = k.tbl_Departmans
    .Where(p=>p.Bolge_ID == Convert.ToInt32(cb_Bolge.ValueMember))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Still, i am getting the same error code in the same block.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you should use Binding. It's cleaner and do everything for you once it's configured.

In your xaml:

```
<combobox name="first" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity, mode=TwoWay}" />
<combobox name="second" ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}" />
```

Then, in your controller, using [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
public class CitySelector : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<City> cities;
    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities
    {
        get { return cities; }
        set
        {
            if (cities != value)
            {
                cities = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Cities");
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Department> departments;
    public ObservableCollection<Department> Departments
    {
        get { return departments; }
        set
        {
            if (departments != value)
            {
                departments = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Departments");
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Department> MyDepartments;

    private City selectedCity;
    public City SelectedCity
    {
        get { return selectedCity; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedCity != value)
            {
                selectedCity = value;
                if (selectedCity == null)
                    Departments = null;
                else
                    Departments = MyDepartments.Where(x => x.CityId == selectedCity.Id).ToList();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedCity");
            }
        }
    }

    public CitySelector()
    {
        MyDepartments = new List<Department>() { new Department() { name = "Dep1", CityId = 1}, new Department() {name = "Dep2", CityId = 2}, new Department() {name = "Dep3", CityId = 3 } };
        Cities = new ObservableCollection<City>() { new City() { Id = 1, name = "City 1" }, new City() { Id = 2, name = "City 2" }, new City() { Id = 3, name = "City 3" } };

        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Give me more informations if I didn't get your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ValueMemberChanged` event but use `SelectedValueChanged` like:

```
private void cb_Bolge_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cb_Bolge.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        cb_Departman.DataSource = k.tbl_Departmans.Where(p=>p.Bolge_ID == Convert.ToInt32(cb_Bolge.SelectedValue));
        cb_Departman.DisplayMember = "Departman_Ad";
        cb_Departman.ValueMember = "Departman_ID";
    }
}
```